Is keeping preserved dead insects inside a glass as a keychain or decoration haram?
Assalamualaikum, me and my family are traveling and we decided to visit a butterfly/insect garden so we saw many beatiful insects and butterflys. my sister then decided to buy a one of those dead insects that are peeserved inside some glass as a gift for my nephew. i want to know if this is halal or not since its an actual dead insect?
